# Bootstrap: On mobile, on the right there is white space and the nav bar is incomplete

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website built with Bootstrap that works fine on desktop, and in landscape mode on mobile but not in portrait mode on mobile. I have white space on the right and the right side of the nav bar is missing.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    {% load static %}
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

  
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">


  </head>
  
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  
         <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center mb-2 mb-sm-0">
             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                 <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'homepage' %}>About</a>
             </li> 

             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'gallery' %}>Gallery</a>
             </li> 

             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5 ">
                <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'guestbook' %}>Guestbook</a>
             </li>
        </ul>

  
     </nav>
     {% block content %}{% endblock %}


    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the wrapper for all of the pages on my website and this problem is consistent across all pages.

My stylesheet is:

```
.img-shrink-100 {
  object-fit: contain; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 100px;
}
.img-shrink-250 {
  object-fit: contain; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 250px;
}
.img-shrink-700 {
  object-fit: contain; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 700px;
}

.p-small {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center { 
  margin: auto;
        } 

.link-color{
  color: #FFF !important;
}
.link-color:hover {
  background-color : #999999;
  color : white !important;
}
.form-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.form-oneline{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Some folks have solved the white on the right problem with `overflow-x:hidden` but this doesn't solve my cut off navbar problem (it does prevent scrolling over to the white)

I'm at a loss as to what is happening but CSS is not my strongest suit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue with your code is that the `navbar-expand` is not what to be used instead it should be paired with `-lg` or `-sm`.

For example in your code you can do:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  
         <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center mb-2 mb-sm-0">
             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                 <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'homepage' %}>About</a>
             </li> 

             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'gallery' %}>Gallery</a>
             </li> 

             <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5 ">
                <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'guestbook' %}>Guestbook</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

Also if you do this you will get a responsive navbar, but the code for `toggler/handburger menu button` and `Navbar Brand` is not added so you may need to add that for the menu to be responsive and hidden behind the button.

The final code should look something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!-- Navbar Brand and Toggler Button Code -->
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Navbar Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <!-- Toggler Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Navbar Menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                    <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'homepage' %}>About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5">
                    <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'gallery' %}>Gallery</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item fs-3 mx-5 ">
                    <a class="nav-link link-color" aria-current="page" href={% url 'guestbook' %}>Guestbook</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi! Yes this fixes it! I'm wondering since my navbar only has three options if there is a way to simply make it shrink instead of collapsing?

Comment: If you want to shrink without collapsing you can try to remove the fs-3 classes from the li tags. The issue is with the Typography is not responsive with the mobile view if you want to use custom font size. So, I think you can just remove those classes or try to use a media query to adjust the font size according to the breakpoint.